# input_text_1.onblur = input_text_2.select();

Tags: javascript, dom, xhtml

In firefox, I made a web page, there are two input text elements: **input_text_1** and **input_text_2**. They behave like password verification: If the content of them is different, i.e. when **onblur** event of **input_text_2** is activated, the onblur's handler will **alert** something and then **select** all text of **input_text_1**.

Actually, this is not easy to be implemented, as I think the events chain is not assured: Maybe, input_text_1 got text selected and then lost focus by some clicking. So, I just hack in the onblur's handler of input_text_1 as follows:

`setTimeout("document.getElementById('input_text_1').select()", 100);`

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code works fine in FireFox/IE/Opera/Safari/Chrome, but WebKit-based browsers not always take focus into input:

```
var blurHandler = function() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
    if( this.value !== input1.value ) {
         alert( 'Passwords are not equal' );
         if( input1.selectionStart ) {
             input1.selectionStart = 0;
             input1.selectionEnd = input1.value.length;
         }
         input1.focus();
         if( input1.select ) input1.select();
    }
};

var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

if( input2.addEventListener )
    input2.addEventListener( 'blur', blurHandler, true );
else
    input2.attachEvent( 'onblur', blurHandler );
```

you can try it http://jsfiddle.net/twilightfeel/3ggP6/3/

Comment: Yes, but question was about FireFox.

Comment: Solution updated for cross-browser purpose. It works fine, except WebKit-based browsers, where input1 not always take focus.